Flutter Dio upload file gets `type 'List<int>' is not a subtype of type 'Uint8List'` error
I try to upload a file with Flutter in Web with Dio. I get the file with file_picker and get the bytes of the file. Then I try to upload the file to my backend but I got an error saying Instance of 'JSArray<int>': type 'List<int>' is not a subtype of type 'Uint8List'
Here is the my code. The last line throws the error.
Seems like for some reason, when it tried to understand the file.bytes with type List<int>, it could not convert it to Uint8List.
Any advice will be appreciated.
final body = <String, dynamic>{};
      if (fields != null) {
        body.addAll(fields);
      }

      body.addAll({
        "files": files
            .map((file) => MultipartFile.fromBytes(
                  file.bytes,
                  filename: file.fileName,
                ))
            .toList()
      });

      final formData = FormData.fromMap(body);

      Response<Map<String, dynamic>> response =
          await dio.postUri<Map<String, dynamic>>(url, data: formData, options: options);


First tell me 2 things: 1. Are you trying to run this for flutter web ? 2. What is the type of your files variable which you are passing in body.addAll. Also if please provide some more code snippet which helps to understand the problem better.

The error is related to this line:
MultipartFile.fromBytes(
                  file.bytes, //Here causes the error
                  filename: file.fileName,
                )

To Fix this error I converted the file to Uint8List this way:
MultipartFile.fromBytes(
                  Uint8List.fromList(file.bytes), 
                  filename: file.fileName,
                )

